# Find the paragraph which begins with "proof of theorem"

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to mark, in red, the paragraph which begins with "proof of theorem".

My code is below:

```
Sub theorem()
    Dim p As Paragraph, d As Document
        For Each p In ActiveDocument
        If p.Range.Words(1) = "Proof " And p.range.words(2) = "of " and p.Range.Words(3) = "theorem " Then
                End If
    End Sub
```

I feel this method “`If p.Range.Words(1) = "Proof " And p.range.words(2) = "of " and p.Range.Words(3) = "theorem "`” is bulky. I would like to ask whether there is a more concise method, or any other tips.

Comment: If there is a `Range.Text` method (and I know very little about the Word object model, so it may or may not exist) you could probably do something like `If Left(p.Range.Text, 16) = "Proof of theorem" Then`.  OK, just tried it, that works.

Comment: @ YowE3K  Perfect solution, thanks

Comment: Or try `If Instr(1, Trim(p.Range.Text), "proof of theorem", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then`. This code would identify the paragraph irrespective of the search string's capitalisation and even if someone inadvertently placed a space before it.

Comment: @ Variatus  Amazing, A more comprehensive method，thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the `Left` function to retrieve the first 16 characters of the paragraph and test that:

```
Sub theorem()
    Dim p As Paragraph, d As Document
    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If Left(p.Range.Text, 16) = "Proof of theorem" Then
            p.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```